# Row_names in data frame

Tags: r, shiny, amazon-rds

I want to do change the name row_names attribute which is default to dataframe in shiny to some other name e.g "id"and also wanted to make "id" as primary key.It is possible?
Here is sample code

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(pool)
pool <- dbPool(drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),dbname = "demo",host = 
"db.cr7lk1dht.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com",username = "ktik",password 
= "12378", port = 3306)
df <- data.frame(0)

ui <- fluidPage(
  submitButton("submit")

  )

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){

  df <- data.frame(
    emp_id = c (1,2,3,4,5), 
   emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
   salary = c(623,515,611,729,843)) 



   dbWriteTable(pool, "ro1", df, overwrite = TRUE) #this will insert the 
entire dataframe at once into dummyTable

})

 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: is it possible that i can make new column in my database table(say T)as soon as whole dataframe output will dump on T e.g if total columns in dataframe is 9, i want total 10 columns in my table T.Please suggest a way to do that @DS_UNI

Comment: To be honest it's not completely clear to me what you want to do, and it seems that this is a strictly database question and has nothing to do with shiny. Let's at least try to make your question clear for people who can help: you already have a table in a database on amazon and you want add a column to it from R?

Comment: dbWriteTable(pool, "ro1", df, overwrite = TRUE)  is creating table named ro1 and i haven't given the definition of this table in my database, this function is automatically creating it and inserting the values which is present in dataframe. Now i want to make a new column in my same database table which is not present in my dataframe and want to make it as primary key. One way is to do that i use "ALTER" query and add "id" column in my table independent of my code but it will give me error when i compile my code and error would be "can't find object id ". @DS_UNI

Comment: one approach might be is that i can make row_names which is default to dataframe as primary key but when i try to do that it is throwing error " BLOB/TEXT column 'row_names' used in key specification without a key length". I will follow any approach which in which you can help me to rectify.Hope i must be clear this time.Thanks for your support @DS_UNI

Comment: For one thing, what you tried to do and the error messages you got should definitely be in the question, add those to the question along with the code you used.
Another thing try to focus the question on the problem, keep only the relevant code, for example I don't see how shiny would fit in to all this, if it doesn't then take it out.
Finally the title doesn't give any indication to what the problem is, it should at least give some clue that you're trying to alter a table in a database or something like this.